# Does SqlDataAdapter close the SqlConnection after Fill() function?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlconnection.close

Does `SqlDataAdapter` close the `SqlConnection` after the `Fill()` function or do I need close it myself?

```
string cnStr = @"Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=Suite;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=app;Password=Immmmmm";
cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Date", cn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

cn.Close() // ????????

Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
Console.WriteLine(cn.State);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your current usage, it will close for you:

> If the IDbConnection
>   is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data and
>   then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it
>   remains open.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx

I think it's always better to explicitly cater for it yourself with a `using` statement:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Do Stuff.

} // Closes here on dispose.
```

This is often more readable and doesn't rely on people understanding the inner workings of `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`, just the `using` statement and connections.

However, if you *know* the connection is closed before the adapter uses it (as in, you've just created the connection) and it's not used for anything else, your code is perfectly safe and valid.

Personally, I'd write something like this:

```
    string cnStr = "Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=Suite;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=app;Password=Immmmmm";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Date", cn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    { 
        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);       
    }
```

Comment: but if I write this code without using construction cn whatever have Closed state before exit of function

Comment: @Wachburn indeed, and consulting MSDN verifies this.  Sorry, I didn't catch this the first time around.

Comment: It handles closing it for you if the command is executed successfully, but what about in an exception case? (deadlock, timeout, etc.)

Comment: @JoelC The `using` statement calls dispose on exception as well, it simply compiles into a try-finally block under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant before introducing the `using` block. You started by saying `In your current usage, it will close for you` but I wanted to clarify whether that would be the case if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @JoelC Oh, in that case no it won't - it will be left for the GC to handle assuming exceptions are handled and don't cause a massive app crash.

Comment: Just to be clear: in your last block of code, the `conn.Open();` isn't actually needed. It's just there in case other programmers don't know that `adapter.Fill(ds);` will open (and close) the connection itself. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. I believe it works both ways, personal preference really.

Comment: There is no need for three separate using statements. The using can have a comma separated list of expressions to create IDisposable objects, and it will create nested try-finally statements for them. One using will suffice here.

Comment: @ConcreteGannet Just tried it in case something had changed for C# 7, but unfortunately that still is only true when the type is shared, such as `using (IDisposable conn = new SqlConnection(), comm = new SqlCommand())` you cannot do `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(), SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())` so three `using` statements are required in this case.

Comment: Thanks @AdamHouldsworth, I hadn't realised that. The using isn't quite as cool as I thought. I agree three usings is the best answer. You could declare them all as IDisposable, then downcast inside the block, but that's very ugly. You could declare them before the using, but that's dangerous because the variables would be still in scope after they've been disposed. Feel free to downvote my comment above, SO won't let me :-)

Answer (score 5):

As I know you need to close the connection by you own

Best way to do is

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
{
   // you code 
}
```

this will close you connection automatically

using block in C# comes very handly while dealing with disposable  objects. Disposable objects are those objects that can explicitly release the resources they use when called to dispose. As we know .Net garbage collection is non-deterministic so you can’t predict when exactly the object will be garbage collected.

Read this post for more in details : [understanding ‘using’ block in C#](http://www.ruchitsurati.net/index.php/2010/07/28/understanding-%E2%80%98using%E2%80%99-block-in-c/)