# Fill nested repeaters in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, sqldatasource, asprepeater

I have a repeater inside another repeater. How can  I display all the fields(surname) from db in an inner repeater. In the function `outerRepeater_ItemDataBound`, `DataSource` isn't recognized. I don't know exactly where I need to select all the surnames for a specific name.

I have this in my repeater.ascx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="outerRepeater" OnItemDataBound="outerRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                 <td><th>Name:</th></td>
                 <td><th>Surname:</th></td>
                </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <h3><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%></h3> 
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="innerRepeater" >
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%#Eval("Surname") %>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this in repeater.ascx.cs

```
public partial class Repeater : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            outerRepeater.DataSource = GetDataSource();
            outerRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    private DataTable GetDataSource()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"my connection string");

        SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Distinct Name FROM Person ORDER BY Name ", myConnection);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myCommand.Fill(dt);

        myConnection.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }
    protected void outerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
           if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
           {
               Repeater innerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater") as Repeater;
               DataTable dt = GetSurname();
               innerRepeater.DataSource = dt;//here isn't su
               innerRepeater.DataBind();
           }
    }

    private DataTable GetSurname()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"my connection string");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Surname from Person ", myConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: I have tweaked your question a bit to remove minor misspellings. I have also removed "Hy", because salutations in questions [are usually frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). And I have removed tag words from the title, because it is a common consensus that [they are not required with correctly set tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Manually adding `Page_Load` handler

I am not sure that you really need to set `Page_Load` event handler in your code-behind. With default page settings it will be wired-up automatically.

Setting it manually is required only if you set the [PagesSection.AutoEventWireup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

## 2. Table with repeater

It is possible to create a table with repeater - [How to create a three column table in ASP.Net Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442897/how-to-create-a-three-column-table-in-asp-net-repeater), but it will require a bit different markup with properly set table tags:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="outerRepeater" OnItemDataBound="outerRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                 <th>Name:</th>
                 <th>Surname:</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%></h3> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="innerRepeater" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("Surname") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>   
            </tbody>             
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And, perhaps, [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) is a better alternative to manual table creation.

## 3. Get all surnames for the given name

You obviously get **all** surnames because `Select Surname from People` doesn't filter anything - it just selects all items. To achieve what you want you will have to add some [WHERE clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)), that filter by name associated with the current row. The `Name` can be obtained through the `e.Item.DataItem` in the `outerRepeater_ItemDataBound` handler.

```
protected void outerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Repeater innerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater") as Repeater;

        String name = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)[0].ToString();

        DataTable dt = GetSurname(name);
        innerRepeater.DataSource = dt;//here isn't su
        innerRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataTable GetSurname(String name)
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Database = TSQL2012"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Surname from Person WHERE Name = @name", myConnection))
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

## 4. Not always disposing the connection

While you call the `Close` method on your connections it is better to use the [`using` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) as it used in the previous code samples, because `using` will guarantee that whatever happens the connection will be closed for sure. The same applies as well to the `SqlDataAdapter`, but whether [it is actually required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388744/does-sqldataadapter-close-the-sqlconnection-after-fill-function) or just a good rule of thumb I do not know.

## 5. Multiple SQL requests

Multiple SQL requests, especially when all the required information is directly related can lead to a very poor performance.  You can either fetch all the names and surnames to process them in the page, or you can apply [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings) to fetch single datatable with all the needed data:

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="outerRepeater">
...
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr >
        <td>
            <h3><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%></h3> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ConcatenatedSurnames")%></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code-behind:

```
private const String SelectCommand = @"
WITH Partitioned AS
(
SELECT Name,
    Surname,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS NameNumber,
    COUNT(*) OVER  (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS NameCount
FROM Person
),
Concatenated AS
(
SELECT Name,
    CAST(Surname AS nvarchar) AS ConcatenatedSurnames, 
    NameNumber, 
    NameCount 
FROM Partitioned 
WHERE NameNumber = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    P.Name, 
    CAST(C.ConcatenatedSurnames + ', ' + P.Surname AS nvarchar), 
    P.NameNumber, 
    P.NameCount
FROM Partitioned AS P
    INNER JOIN Concatenated AS C 
    ON P.Name = C.Name AND 
        P.NameNumber = C.NameNumber + 1
)
SELECT 
Name,
ConcatenatedSurnames
FROM Concatenated
WHERE NameNumber = NameCount";

private DataTable GetDataSource()
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Database = TSQL2012"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand, myConnection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myCommand.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```